# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null | Angular 7

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, firebase

I'm trying to access Observable in component.html like this:

```
{{ (pins | async)[0]?.state }}
```

I don't know if it can be done this way but I want to access single part of Observable list in html **without looping with *ngFor**. (I am working with firebase.)
Here is component.ts:

```
pins: Observable<any[]>;

this.pins = this.db.list('pins').snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(changes => 
    changes.map(c => ({ $key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
  )
);
```

And here is json data of pins:

```
[
  {
    "$key": "0",
    "pin": 5,
    "state": true
  },
  {
    "$key": "1",
    "pin": 4,
    "state": false
  },
  {
    "$key": "2",
    "pin": 0,
    "state": true
  },
  {
    "$key": "3",
    "pin": 2,
    "state": false
  },
  {
    "$key": "4",
    "pin": 14,
    "state": true
  },
  {
    "$key": "5",
    "pin": 12,
    "state": true
  },
  {
    "$key": "6",
    "pin": 13,
    "state": true
  },
  {
    "$key": "7",
    "pin": 15,
    "state": true
  }
]
```

It is working for first item but others don't and it shows this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (HomeComponent.html:88)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:22503)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21878)
    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22056)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21879)
    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:22077)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21874)
    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: have you add `*ngIf="pins"`?. before use `ping`.

Comment: I tried now but still same error

Comment: can you create minimal `https://stackblitz.com/`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1uon89  (not connected to my firebase)

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: @TimotejSofijanović I'm using simple array like you provide your data and show on browser check it is work for you or you want any changes in that let me know.(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1uon89?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check the length of the variable first and then use index position to get the specified item from the list:

So your HTML Like:

```
<ul *ngFor="let pin of pins;let i=index">
    <li>{{ pin.state }} <button mat-button (click)="update(i,pin)">Update Status</button></li>
</ul>
<span *ngIf="pins">
   {{ pins[0].state }} and {{pins.length}}
</span>
```

In TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  pins: any;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.db.list('pins').valueChanges().subscribe(value => {
      this.pins = value;
    });
  }
  update(i,pin)
  {
   this.db.object('/pins/' + i).update({ pin: pin.pin, state: !pin.state });
  }
}
```

[`WORKING EXAMPLE`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ba1xyz)

Comment: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}

Comment: Still dont work... here is stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1uon89

Comment: This answer works but it is not Observable so I don't get updates in real-time. I found my way to solve this but only because this part of database is static and keys go from 0 to 7. I made list of Observables:  `pins: Observable<any>[] = new Array();` `for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      this.pin[i] = this.db.object('pins/' + i).valueChanges();
    }` Thanks for help, stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1uon89

Comment: Ok there is not Firebase connection can you provide that?

Comment: @TimotejSofijanović Nope its retrieving object when it gets added: check here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ba1xyz

Comment: @TimotejSofijanović check the updated StackBlitz have added option to add new item to check real time data fetch

Comment: I don't need to add in this case only get and update(set)

Comment: Still working on that i need to get somehow pin state (bool) from template to component. I want to make button that changes pin state on click

Comment: @TimotejSofijanović I think this is what you wanted? --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ba1xyz

Answer (score 0):

component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
      pins: Observable<any[]>;
      pinsList = [];

      constructor(...) { }

      ngOnInit() {
       ...
       pins..subscribe(pins => this.pinsList = pins);
      }

    }
```

component.html

```
{{ pins[0].state }}
```

or use:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pin of pins | async; let i = index;">
 <div  *ngIf="i === 0">{{ pin.state }}</div>
</ng-container>
```